# Получение доступа к элементам формы C# из пользовательских классов

Tags: winforms, c#

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема. Создал Windows приложение в C#. На форме расположен, к примеру, textbox. В файле Program.cs создал несколько своих классов, но при попытке обратиться к textboх этого сделать не удается (типо он не существует).
Попробовал перекинуть иерархию классов в класс Form1 из Form1.cs - теперь оно то можно выбрать TextBox, пишет, что cannot acces to non-static member и т.п. и т.д.

Как можно получить доступ к textboxу, желательно несколько вариантов и как оптимальнее.

Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш textbox есть член класса `Form1`, доступ к нему возможен внутри функций-членов класса `Form1`,

`Form1.cs`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void DoSomeStuffWithTextBox()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "some text";
        }
    }
}
```

А по объекту класса через точку из чужих классов -- невозможен, поскольку уровень доступа textbox'ов, вставляемых через дизайнер форм `private`

`Form1.Designer.cs`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
................................

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Хотя, Вы можете вручную изменить уровень доступа для `textBox1` на `public` в этом файле ;) <костыль/>. И, хотя файл генерируется автоматически, при изменении формы Ваша правка сохранится (если не удалять `textBox1` с формы, конечно).

Лучше всего в форме сделать публичный метод (или свойство), возвращающий ссылку на `textBox1`.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
.....................
        public TextBox getTextBox()
        {
            return textBox1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающее объяснение)

Comment: и как  вызвать getTextBox() из другого класса?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так

```
 Form1 childForm = new Form1();
 // класс Form1 должен быть public
 childForm.textBox1;
```

При этом сделайте тип доступа `textBox1 public` так, как написал ArtFeel или в дизайнере класса `Form1.Designer` найдите свой текст бокс и задайте тип доступа вместо private - public

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я помню, можно еще в дизайнере кликнуть по TextBox'y и в Свойствах изменить метод доступа на public.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий к ответу yapycoder